# Jewish,Persian and Arabic DateTime model binding in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-binding

Some countries like **Iran**, **Israel** and **Saudi Arabia** use their special calendar. For example Gregorian date "**2012-12-11**" is "**1391-09-21**" in Iranian calendar. For many reasons(E.g. database functionality) we decided to store our date variables in database with Gregorian date format. The challenge begin when we want to build UI for that. In `asp.net mvc` it's easy to create a template and change the `DateTime` variable to suitable format. But the problem is in **post back** where the returned value is not recognized by `mvc` model binder (note that the days in month are not equal with Gregorian date).
One way to fix this is to parse the incoming result, like:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Create(Content person,string customBirthdayDate)
{   
     person.Birthday = CustomDateTimeHelper.Parse(customBirthdayDate);
     Service.Save(person);            
     return RedirectToAction("List");  
}
```

Which works fine, but i am looking for better solution. An idea was to change the model to:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id{set;get;}
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public DateTime Birthday{set;get;}
    public string CustomBirthdayDate
    {
      set{Birthday = CustomDateTimeHelper.Parse(value);}
      get{return CustomDateTimeHelper.ConvertToCustomDate(Birthday); }
    }
}
```

In this this approach there is no need to write extra code in Controllers Action.
Any better idea ??
Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you need to work out how to change the culture during the parse part, so that it's a culture with an appropriate default calendar.

Comment: @ghazyy if you could use Jquery ui  i would help you out with this.

Comment: Instead storing DateTime in database store `epoch` timestamp in UTC +0 zone, which can be easily converted to any local or calendar as and when required. This is the recommended approach as well instead storing datetime.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara @BojanB Yay, lets dig up some super old unanswered questions.. nice job everyone! Lets get serious: the main problem seems to be the representation of gregorian february, where the persian calendar allows day of month 30, which is out of range for the gregorian calendar. Consequently, `DateTime` can't be used for the UI of persian applications. For the sake of coding, [`PersianDateTime`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850359/Persian-Calendar-PersianDateTime-in-Csharp?fid=1874591&df=10000&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=5259181) might help.